# Getting Users Geo Location API 23

Tags: android, geolocation

Every time I run this, I get this error message "java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"

I need to get the users longitude and latitude so I can use it for the rest of my app, but I cannot figure out how to get past this error.

```
    public class map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private FloatingActionButton plus;
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    plus = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.newPlace);

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(map.this, newPlacePop.class));
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    float zoomLevel = 16; //This goes up to 21
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, zoomLevel));

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

You have a field initializer that is calling `getSystemService()`:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

You cannot call `getSystemService()` — or most other methods that you are inheriting from `Activity` — before the call to `super.onCreate()` in your `onCreate()` method.

So, change:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

to:

```
LocationManager lm;
Location location;
double longitude;
double latitude;
```

and add the following lines after `super.onCreate()` in your `onCreate()` method:

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (location==null) {
  // do something
}
else {
  longitude = location.getLongitude();
  latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
```

> I need to get the users longitude and latitude so I can use it for the rest of my app

Your code is unlikely to get the latitude and longitude. `getLastKnownLocation()` frequently returns `null`, and you would crash with a `NullPointerException` without the `if` check in the code shown above. You may wish to read [the documentation on getting location data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

Also, you mention "API 23". If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you need [the code to request your location permission at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).